# scan for a specified class on a bunch of classes in a element jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this html structure

```
<body class="blog page current-page page-50452">

    <div class="content"></div>

</body>
```

I want to scan the classes in the body element and then if the specified class was found in the body element then a process will be executed, the concept is like below:

```
//the jquery/javascript version..

var cc = $('body').find('.blog'); //this assume to find the blog class in the body element..

if ( if the blog class has found in the body element then..){

//this is the work that i want to implement, like, it add another div with class and contents after the <div class="content">

$('.content').after('<div></div>').addClass('pagination').html('hello');

}else{

// here if the blog class is not found in the body element.

}
```

as you can see in the above codes, it first get all the classes from the body element and then scan on the classes if the blog class is exist, if the blog class is found then it should add this

```
<div class="pagination">hello</div>
```

after the

```
<div class="content">..
```

so far the codes above doesn't work unfortunately, so currently im looking around for some solutions regarding my issue yet so far it seems like im unfortunate.

please correct my codes, im open in any suggestions, recommendations and ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, something like:

```
if($('body').hasClass('blog')){
  $('.content').each(function(){
    $(this).after("<div class='pagination'>Hello!</div>");
  });
}
```

See,

http://api.jquery.com/after/

for more information. Version info is located in horizontal blue on the right.

Comment: `if($('body.blog'))` its not correct, if the body doesn't have the class, it'll return an empty array, and that's a truthy value

Comment: The above code would insert the contents inside `.after()` on every `class='content'` within you `body`. It should work on version 1.8.1.

Comment: Seeing that you accepted this answer, the each it's redundant here, jQuery will do it if the matched elements are an array.

Comment: does this work also if i want to add those contents after the specified element that has a id selector? can i use also an image as a content that i want to be added after a element that has a id selector? for example i want to add <div class="image"><img src="images/image.jpg" /></div> after <div id="content">?

Comment: oh it fix now, i just added few more codes to meet my demands, thank you very much!.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if ( $("body").hasClass("blog") ){
```

Using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) you are getting the descendants of the body filtered by the selector, witch is not what you want

Also, to add the pagination div, I suggest this:

```
$('<div>', {
    "class": "pagination",
    "html": "hello"
}).insertAfter('.content');
```

Comment: Actually, the second line I wrote was added in 1.4. You can use them with 1.8.1 :)

Comment: how about javascript version for this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about that, jQuery has your back, you can use this in every modern browser, and IE >= 6.

Comment: does this work also if i want to add those contents after the specified element that has a id selector? can i use also an image as a content that i want to be added after a element that has a id selector? for example i want to add <div class="image"><img src="images/image.jpg" /></div> after <div id="content">?

Comment: change the string `'.content'` for `'#content'` to add it to that element, change the class from `pagination` to `image`, and change the html to `'<img src="images/image.jpg" />'`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do

```
if ($(" body .blog")){
//do stuff
}
```

This way if there is no element `.blog` in body the selector will return undefined, so the condition will be false.

Comment: The selector will not return undefined, it'll return an empty array, that will always be true.

Comment: Also, you're looking for elements with the class .blog inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the body with class blog using `$('body.blog').size()`.

If you want to avoid if statement, you can try:

```
function AppendPagination() {
  ($('body.blog').size() > 0) &&
  $('.content').after("<div class='pagination'>hello</div>");
}
```

This will *short-circuit* the execution, when `body.blog` doesn't exist.